# Encode String with UTF-8 in GWT

Tags: gwt, utf-8

Is there a way to encode a String with UTF-8 in GWT?  In other words, is there a GWT-compatible equivalent to java.net.URLEncoder.encode(toEncode, "UTF-8")?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's com.google.gwt.http.client.Url.encode(), JavaDoc: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html