# GWT: Encode `'` characters in string

Tags: java, gwt, character-encoding

I need to encode a string in such a way that ASCII punctuation character `'` will be encoded too. When we don't use gwt it looks like

`URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");`

and it works exactly as I expect.

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139698/encode-string-with-utf-8-in-gwt) about URLEncoder equivalent in gwt. But according to the documentation, ASCII punctuation characters

`- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

will not be escaped by method `com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encode(string)`.

What is the right way to encode a string such that all `'` will be encoded too?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASCII chars only this would encode all:

```
String string = "asc<>&-_()'";
String encoded = "";
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    encoded+= "&#x" + Integer.toHexString(Character.valueOf(c)) + ";";
}
```

The output is:

```
&#x61;&#x73;&#x63;&#x3c;&#x3e;&#x26;&#x2d;&#x5f;&#x28;&#x29;&#x27;
```